# express restAPI, how to properly validate requests and respond invalid requests?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express, database-design

**My Environments:**

Backend: Express Server connected to Postgres.
Client: React hosted on a seperate server.

**My example, I have a POST/signup endpoint on my express server that takes the following:**

1. Username
2. Email
3. Password

**Correct me if I'm wrong, the backend will need to verify the following validation:**

1. check req.body that username, email and password are all present, otherwise respond:

```js
res.status(400).send({ msg: "Please pass
    username/email/password." });
```

2. check if username, email are already in the database

```js
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = 'bee' OR email = 'bee@gmail.com';

/*
if exists, res.status(400).send({ msg: "Username/Email already exists" });
else res.status(200).json({message: "successfully signed up"})
*/
```

3. *** Do I need to add an additional format validation? i.e unacceptable characters for username, before I carry on inserting it into database.

I ponder on this because I can imagine client-side may help with these tedious validation with formik/yup etc. But should i worry about the few people who make direct communication to my API without using my client application? Unless CORs help fix this problem?

4. *** How should i handle errors in general. Do i handle backend db/express request error via try...catch blocks to return    `res.status(400).json({message: "server error"});`

---

And one final thing, on step 2. Can I technically skip verifying whether username/email already exists and immediately insert the data anyways because postgreSQL will notify me if any unique values/constraints are affected... I can take postgreSQL error and transfer that to the client side? - if this is the way, I also have no idea how to do that.

**Don't know if this matters:**

I should note that, my express server is NOT also serving webpages. this express server is only a restAPI to provide some authentication logic/with sessions to use my DB for my client-side.

I know its a lot of questions. if you have a way better strategy/resource, I would love to hear it. Or if there any any good libraries to help with development i would love know about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Do I need to add an additional format validation?** CORS can limit the origin who can send requests to your server, so it might help. But AFAIK, it doesn't block requests from Node.js code or Postman for example. So you will also need input validation on the server-side (and you should always do that).
2. **How should I handle errors in general?** You can read the best practice from [here](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#2-error-handling-practices)(the **Error Handling Practices** part). For me, in the logic code, I throw an error with a descriptive message and using a middleware to send error message to client (like you did `res.status(400).json({message: "server error"});`). Also, you need to log the error.
3. **Can I technically skip verifying whether username/email already exists and immediately insert the data anyways because postgreSQL will notify me**. Technically you can do that, but the error throws by Postgre is long and hard to read. Anythings like unique username/email is application logic. I always handle it by myself instead of delegating it to the database layer.

Some helpful libraries to do the validation :

- [NodeJS JOI](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0)
- [Express Validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Comment: is JOI and express validator used together?
i assume JOI is similar as YUP

Comment: I don't use Joi and Express validator in the same project. I think 1 is enough.